# Como definir index ao inserir item no JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

Gostaria de saber se alguém me poderia ajudar.
Estou a tentar adicionar itens a uma `JComboBox`:

```
Pessoa carlos = new Pessoa(12, "Carlos" , 0.0f);
jComboBoxF.addItem(carlos.getNome());
Pessoa maria = new Pessoa(23, "Maria" ,0.0f);
jComboBoxF.addItem(maria.getNome());
```

Neste caso a `JComboBox` fica no index "0" como o valor "Carlos", e no index "1" com o valor Maria.

O que gostava de saber era se ao adicionar o nome também era possível adicionar o index, de maneira a ficar neste caso com dois identificadores o 12 e o 23, 12 para o valor Carlos e 23 para o valor Maria.

Por outras palavras quero usar os id's das Pessoas como index da `JComboBox`.

O que pretendo com isto é usar o index da `JComboBox` para identificar a Pessoa em questão, já que o index da combo desta maneira seria o próprio ID da Pessoa.

Comment: Carlos será sempre o décimo-terceiro item da JComboBox? Maria será sempre a vigésima-quarta na lista? Ou a lista tem apenas esses elementos mesmo?

Comment: Neste caso a JComboBox só teria dois elementos, o Carlos e a Maria. Os seus indexes são 0 e 1 e eu gostava de poder escolher ao inserir por exemplo 12 e 23.

Comment: Então me parece que você não entendeu o que o index da `JComboBox` quer dizer. É como se fosse um array, o index 0 é o primeiro item, o index 1 é o segundo item, o index 2 é o terceiro item... E isso não vai dar certo se você quer ter apenas dois itens com os indexes 12 e 23. Acredito que o que você quer de verdade é recuperar esse número que está dentro do objeto da pessoa, que é exatamente o que eu mostrei com a minha resposta, pois pelo que você descreve a posição e a ordem delas na `JComboBox` não é relevante para você, apenas o número que você associou a cada Pessoa é.

Comment: Eu sei como o index funciona e qual a sua importância, estava na duvida é se haveria alguma forma de manipular os index e já chegamos à conclusão que não. O problema fica resolvido se colocar o objecto na JComboBox e não apenas o nome de maneira a poder aceder a todos os atributos do objecto. O meu muito obrigado, problema resolvido.

Answer (score 2):

**André**,

se você estiver utilizando um `model` em seu `JComboBox` que implementa a `interface` `MutableComboBoxModel` você conseguirá fazer:

```
((MutableComboBoxModel) jComboBox.getModel()).insertElementAt(carlos, 0);
((MutableComboBoxModel) jComboBox.getModel()).insertElementAt(maria, 1);
```

Mas eu fortemente lhe aconselho a criar a lista de itens antes de colocar no seu `JComboBox`, algo como:

```
List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();
pessoas.add(new Pessoa(12, "Carlos" , 0.0f));//adicionando o carlos na lista
pessoas.add(new Pessoa(23, "Maria" ,0.0f));

//com a lista pronta, altere o model no seu jComboBox
jComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(pessoas.toArray()));
```

Quando você diz que quer que o index seja 12 ou 23, isso só será possível se você tiver mais de 23 itens no seu `jComboBox`. O index no caso é a posição que o elemento está no seu `jComboBox`, sendo 0 a primeira posição até tamanho da lista -1.

O que talvez você queira é que exiba esses números junto ao nome no seu `jComboBox`. Para isso você só precisa sobrescrever o método `toString()` na sua classe `Pessoa`.

```
public class Pessoa{

  private String nome;
  private int idade;

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return idade + " - " + nome;
  }

}
```

Assim seu `jComboBox` exibirá os itens assim:

- 12 - Carlos
- 23 - Maria

Comment: Desde já o meu muito obrigado pela resposta e pela dica. O meu objectivo não é apresentar na combo mais do que o nome da pessoa. Não é isso que pretendo. A minha ideia era usar os id's das pessoas como index da jcombox de maneira que quando escolhesse um item pudesse usar o index da combo para identificar a Pessoa em questão. Só não sei se é possível e se possível não sei como o fazer. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Ah sim. Mas ai você terá que garantir que suas pessoas possuam id's crescentes, que não falte nenhum e todas essas pessoas esteja no `jComboCox`. Bastaria ordenar a lista e colocá-la nele. No caso você teria que ter id's do 0... ao 24 para poder usar o  index 12 e 23.

Comment: Pois, então não dá para fazer o que pretendo. Assim eu sei fazer... Vou ter de pensar noutra forma. Muito Obrigado

Comment: Ao usar " jComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(pessoas.toArray())); " a combo apresenta qualquer coisa como "nomedopackages.Pessoas@umnumero" :)

Comment: Sobrescreveu o `toString()` de sua classe Pessoa? Exibirá o que você colocar para retorno no `toString()` , se não o sobrescrever exibe o endereço de memória

Answer (score 1):

Aqui está um exemplo funcional do que você quer. Basicamente o segredo é implementar o método `toString()` adequadamente.

```
package testes;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TesteComboBox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(TesteComboBox::exemplo);
    }

    private static void exemplo() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Exemplo");
        JComboBox<Pessoa> jComboBoxF = new JComboBox<>();
        jf.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jf.add(jComboBoxF);

        Pessoa carlos = new Pessoa(12, "Carlos", 0.0f);
        Pessoa maria = new Pessoa(23, "Maria", 0.0f);
        jComboBoxF.addItem(carlos);
        jComboBoxF.addItem(maria);

        JButton mensagem = new JButton("Mostrar");
        jf.add(mensagem);
        mensagem.addActionListener(e -> {
            int idx = jComboBoxF.getSelectedIndex();
            if (idx == -1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "Você não escolheu ninguém.");
            } else {
                Pessoa escolha = jComboBoxF.getItemAt(jComboBoxF.getSelectedIndex());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "Você escolheu " + escolha.getNome() + " de id " + escolha.getId());
            }
        });

        jf.pack();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class Pessoa {
        private final int id;
        private final String nome;
        private final double outraCoisa;

        public Pessoa(int id, String nome, double outraCoisa) {
            this.id = id;
            this.nome = nome;
            this.outraCoisa = outraCoisa;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public double getOutraCoisa() {
            return outraCoisa;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getNome();
        }
    }
}
```

Se o objeto que você quer adicionar na combobox não pode ter um método `toString()` adequado, então use uma classe auxiliar com o `toString()` adequado:

```
public class MinhaClasseAuxiliar {
    private final Pessoa p;
    public MinhaClasseAuxiliar(Pessoa p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public Pessoa getPessoa() {
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // Aqui você faz o que quiser.
    }
}
```

E então você adiciona objtos da classe auxiliar ao invés de acrescentar `Pessoa`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Não é bem isso que eu pretendo. Já editei a pergunta de maneira a esclarecer melhor a duvida. Mas desde já obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 0):

Eu entendi sua dúvida! Porém não sei se isso ainda vai servir para você depois de tanto tempo, mas de repente pode servir para outra pessoa. Neste link tem algo que possa servir para você: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/1891/adicionado-objetos-a-combobox.aspx

Comment: Onde que isso adiciona um item alterando o index do combobox??

Comment: Amigo, veja no link, lá fica mais claro a resposta! Está em c#, mas da pra entender e aplicar no java a lógica sugerida.

Comment: Se a resposta depende do link pra fazer sentido, então não é uma boa resposta. O link deve ser apenas de complemento, não possuir a solução. O código também não faz o solicitado na pergunta. Se no link tem mais informações que possam solucionar a pergunta, sugiro que adicione, pois este código não resolve o problema. Sem contar que esse código ta parecendo ser em C# e a linguagem da pegunta é java!

Comment: OK, obrigado pelas considerações!

Comment: Não dá pra aplicar isso em java, o funcionamento do window forms e do swing não é nem de longe semelhante.

Comment: Eu apliquei e deu certo pra mim.

Comment: Veja as outras respostas, a lógica do seu código não está nem parecida com as das outras. É só uma dica, se a pergunta for de uma linguagem, evite postar solução em outra, a não ser que o usuário que perguntou deixar isso claro na pergunta.